# getting Error while installing the magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

I am installing the Magento and followed all the steps and passed all the requirements, yet it throws an error at the last step of installation.

Error Log:

> [ERROR] exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid backend frontname ' in /var/www/mysite/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/DeploymentConfig/BackendConfig.php:32

[image]

Comment: http://www.mbyte.in/magento2-installation/

Comment: Follow the below blog  and install the magento2 http://www.magechimp.com/magento2-installation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this error by giving full permissions right (777) to magento folder. Also check your database name.

Comment: after set permissions 777 resolved the above issue but occured below one after 94 % installation

Comment: Now you need to increase value 100 to 300  in php.ini variable "max_nesting_level" php.ini file
IF you have installed xdebug then you need to change in php.ini file in xdebug.